# GCC 4.7.2 requires ppl?

Tags: linux, gcc

I'm trying to configure GCC 4.7.2, but it's failing with `configure: error: Unable to find a usable PPL`

I've looked in [GCC prerequisites page](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html) and PPL isn't mentioned anywhere.

I'm using [CLooG 0.17.0](http://www.cloog.org/), which uses [ISL](http://freecode.com/projects/isl), and as such no longer requires PPL (as far as I can tell)

Is there some other requirement on PPL in GCC which means I still need PPL, or am I missing some flag from my `configure` line?

I am passing the following options to `configure`:

- `--enable-cloog-backend=isl`
- `--with-cloog=$PREFIX`
- `--with-isl=$PREFIX`
- `--with-gmp=$PREFIX`
- `--with-mpfr=$PREFIX`
- `--with-mpc=$PREFIX`

For completeness, my full configure line is as follows:

```
./configure --prefix=/hostname/tmp/syddev/sdk/gcc472/suse11/x86_64 \
   --disable-multilib --enable-cloog-backend=isl \
   --with-mpc=/hostname/tmp/syddev/sdk/gcc472/suse11/x86_64 \
   --with-mpfr=/hostname/tmp/syddev/sdk/gcc472/suse11/x86_64 \
   --with-gmp=/hostname/tmp/syddev/sdk/gcc472/suse11/x86_64 \
   --with-isl=/hostname/tmp/syddev/sdk/gcc472/suse11/x86_64 \
   --with-cloog=/hostname/tmp/syddev/sdk/gcc472/suse11/x86_64 \
   --build=x86_64-suse-linux --with-pkgversion='SIG build 11/27/2012' \
   --with-gxx-include-dir=/hostname/tmp/syddev/sdk/gcc472/suse11/x86_64/include/c++/4.7.2 \
   --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs
```

**Update:**

In order to try make forward progress I decided to add [PPL](http://bugseng.com/products/ppl) to my installation list, and add `--with-ppl=$PREFIX` to my configure line.

Configure still fails with `configure: error: Unable to find a usable PPL`

It seems this is a bug in the `configure` script: Configure fails if `PPL_MINOR_VERSION < 11`

With the latest version `PPL_MINOR_VERSION=0` (and `PPL_MAJOR_VERSION=1`)

Comment: Have you built and installed ISL already?  Could it be that it is finding an older ISL that needs PPL?  I've not (yet) run into the problem; I'm still using GCC 4.7.1 without the ISL and CLooG components.

Comment: I've installed the latest (and required) isl version - 10.0. It is also the only isl available in my `--with-isl` / `$PREFIX` location

Comment: I suggest to ask on gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The GCC Prerequisites page jumped the gun and is showing the prerequisites for GCC 4.8.

GCC 4.7.2 still uses PPL instead of ISL, as evidenced by the lack of `--with-isl=PATH` in the output of `configure`:

```
Optional Packages:
  --with-PACKAGE[=ARG]    use PACKAGE [ARG=yes]
  --without-PACKAGE       do not use PACKAGE (same as --with-PACKAGE=no)
  --with-build-libsubdir=DIR  Directory where to find libraries for build system
  --with-mpc=PATH         specify prefix directory for installed MPC package.
                          Equivalent to --with-mpc-include=PATH/include plus
                          --with-mpc-lib=PATH/lib
  --with-mpc-include=PATH specify directory for installed MPC include files
  --with-mpc-lib=PATH     specify directory for the installed MPC library
  --with-mpfr-dir=PATH    this option has been REMOVED
  --with-mpfr=PATH        specify prefix directory for installed MPFR package.
                          Equivalent to --with-mpfr-include=PATH/include plus
                          --with-mpfr-lib=PATH/lib
  --with-mpfr-include=PATH
                          specify directory for installed MPFR include files
  --with-mpfr-lib=PATH    specify directory for the installed MPFR library
  --with-gmp-dir=PATH     this option has been REMOVED
  --with-gmp=PATH         specify prefix directory for the installed GMP
                          package. Equivalent to
                          --with-gmp-include=PATH/include plus
                          --with-gmp-lib=PATH/lib
  --with-gmp-include=PATH specify directory for installed GMP include files
  --with-gmp-lib=PATH     specify directory for the installed GMP library
  --with-host-libstdcxx=L use linker arguments L to link with libstdc++ when
                          linking with PPL
  --with-stage1-ldflags=FLAGS
                          linker flags for stage1
  --with-stage1-libs=LIBS libraries for stage1
  --with-boot-libs=LIBS   libraries for stage2 and later
  --with-boot-ldflags=FLAGS
                          linker flags for stage2 and later
  --with-ppl=PATH         specify prefix directory for the installed PPL
                          package. Equivalent to
                          --with-ppl-include=PATH/include plus
                          --with-ppl-lib=PATH/lib
  --with-ppl-include=PATH specify directory for installed PPL include files
  --with-ppl-lib=PATH     specify directory for the installed PPL library
  --with-cloog=PATH       Specify prefix directory for the installed CLooG-PPL
                          package. Equivalent to
                          --with-cloog-include=PATH/include plus
                          --with-cloog-lib=PATH/lib
  --with-cloog-include=PATH
                          Specify directory for installed CLooG include files
  --with-cloog-lib=PATH   Specify the directory for the installed CLooG
                          library
  --with-build-sysroot=SYSROOT
                          use sysroot as the system root during the build
  --with-debug-prefix-map='A=B C=D ...'
                          map A to B, C to D ... in debug information
  --with-build-config='NAME NAME2...'
                          use config/NAME.mk build configuration
  --with-build-time-tools=PATH
                          use given path to find target tools during the build
```

It's unfortunate that they don't maintain prerequisites pages for versions prior to 4.8.